# nested If statement in excel

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to find out how many rows on a worksheet satisfy multiple conditions in different columns. This formula

```
=COUNT(IF(IF(sheet1!$F:$F="Value1",sheet1!$A:$A,0)="Value2",1,""))
```

gives me the correct answer when I am looking at the result in the formula dialog box, but when I close this dialog the answer on the worksheet is either 1 or zero.  The same thing happens using SUM.  What am I doing wrong?

note: using excel 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an array formula. As such, use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work.

Otherwise, the formula will work only for the row in which the formula was put in.

E.g. if the formula is in cell B2, it will evaluate for cells F2 and A2 only.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I never realised I could have a single line array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007 you can use the COUNTIFS formula.

Syntax:
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]...)